# How to reference attributes in deep associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, erb, refinerycms

### **Summary**

Rails 3.2 with RefineryCMS 2.0. These are my pseudocode models:

```
Industry
  name
  has_many companies
  has_many works through companies

Company 
  name
  has_many works
  belongs_to industry

Work
  name
  belongs to company
```

From an instance of Work, I can say work.company.name and get a the name of the associated company.  I would expect it to follow that I could also say company.industry.name without a problem.  However, I am getting an unhelpful error:

```
wrong constant name Refinery:Industries
```

What I would ultimately like to do is follow my associations all the way up ie work.company.industry.name, but the chain is broken between company and industry it seems.
What am I doing wrong here?  Here's my code in more detail.

---

### **Code**

Here are my models.  Any idea what would prevent me from accessing industry attributes from an associated company given that industries have_many companies (companys lol) and companies belong_to an industry?  Any help would be much appreciated.

***Industry Model***

```
module Refinery
  module Industries
    class Industry < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      ...

      attr_accessible :name, :description, :position
      has_many :companys, :class_name => '::Refinery::Companys::Company', :dependent => :nullify
      has_many :works, :through => :companys
    end
  end
end
```

***Company Model***

```
module Refinery
  module Companys
    class Company < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      ...

      attr_accessible :name, :position, :industry_id
      has_many :works, :class_name => '::Refinery::Works::Work', :dependent => :destroy
      belongs_to :industry, :class_name => '::Refinery:Industries::Industry'
    end
  end
end
```

***Work Model***

```
module Refinery
  module Works
    class Work < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      ...

      attr_accessible :name, :description, :position, :company_id
      belongs_to :thumbnail, :class_name => '::Refinery::Image'
      belongs_to :Company, :class_name => '::Refinery::companys::company'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my erb file I'm doing this:

```
<% @works.each do |work| %>          
    ...
    <h5>
      <%= work.company.name %>
    </h5>
<% end %>
```

That one works.
This one gives me an error though:

```
 <% @clients.each do |client| %>
   <h5>
       <%= client.industry.name %>
   </h5>
 <% end %>
```

That error reads:

```
wrong constant name Refinery:Industries
```

Comment: Maybe a typo? `'::Refinery:Industries::Industry'` it is missing a colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least a double colon missing in your `Company` model:

```
belongs_to :industry, :class_name => '::Refinery:Industries::Industry'
```

should be

```
belongs_to :industry, :class_name => '::Refinery::Industries::Industry'
```

I haven't really looked at the rest of the code, but this is a first error.

Comment: yep - it was that colon.  thanks so much for going through my code.  sometimes all you need are fresh eyes, eh?